# C# XML ignore < and > characters in a node

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I'm getting an xml document from a PHP script.

The XML schema looks something like this:

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <ID> 
       123g8fdg
    </ID>
    <Name>
       Michael
    </Name>
    <Note>
       Some notes, for example a small xml snippet: <randomxml><...
    </Note>
  </Item>    
</Items>
```

The Note node could have any value (even an XML snippet)
While trying on getting the following XML data back from the server, I noticed, that the C# **LoadXML** function fails if the Note is the following:

```
"Finish date <= Start date + 1 year"
```

The "<" character breaks it up (I can see that even in the C# XML Visualizer while debugging)

Any ways to ignore any specific XML element in the notes section, so it doesn't interfere with the parser and basic structure?

Comment: Given XML is not valid, you should use CDATA here instead plain text, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Comment: Go fix your PHP script. If your XML contains that text inside an element, it's not valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the value `<` as `&lt;`. You can't use `<` because it is mistaken for opening of tag.

[**Here is online encoding tool for xml**](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=encode&charset=us_ascii)

Comment: So you proposal is to read the XML in C#, then post that data to an online form, read it back in C# and then start processing it?

Comment: @ThomasWeller No I propose to check this online tool if he has some doubts if an element need encoding.